# Asciidoc autonumbering callouts with modified start number

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm currently using Asciidoc to document a YAML code snippet with auto-numbered callouts. The problem I'm having is I'd like to start the callouts at "2" instead of the default "1". This would allow me to reuse the first callout throughout the snippet, since this doesn't work for auto-numbering. I'm able to start the callout descriptions by adding `[start=2]` but can't seem to get that to work in the code snippet.

Here's an example:

```
[source,yaml, start=2]
----
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: example.com <1>
controlPlane: <.>
  hyperthreading: Enabled <.> <.>
  name: master
  platform:
    azure:
      osDisk: <1>
        diskSizeGB: 1024 <.>
      type: Standard_D8s_v3
  replicas: 3
  azureVar: 78 <.>
  test: z <.>
----
[start=2]
<1> baseDomain and osDisk
<.> controlPlane
<.> h1
<.> h2
<.> diskSizeGB
<.> Gov
<.> test
```

I've attached the screenshot of rendered HTML below: You can see the `controlPlane` code callout starting at "1" instead of the preferred "2", whereas the callout description worked as expected. Any idea if this is possible?
[image]

Comment: I'm curious: why would you want to repeat a callout? Often, the callout's description could describe the commonality that exists in multiple locations. That said, I'm not aware of a solution. You might want to file an issue: https://gitlab.com/antora/antora/-/issues

Comment: I repeat callouts when I want to point out to some similarities or differences in several parts of code. So, I have the same problem.
That's said, the goal should be not to start auto-numbering from 2 or anything else, but to repeat/reuse number used somewhere above. And the question is then how to mark (tag) that *repeated* callout.

And I think the issue should be opened in Asciidoctor.
Original implementation of autonumbering was described here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2871 They explicitly decided that for repeating callouts auto-numbering should not be used.